# not a GROUP BY expression error with grouping

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm getting error as not group by expression even though grouped

```
with t2 as(
SELECT numberofplaces,c.eventid, numberofplaces - COUNT(a.memberid) as tot1
FROM event c
INNER JOIN eventmember a 
ON c.eventid = a.eventid
GROUP BY c.eventid,numberofplaces)
select t2.numberofplaces,tot1 - count(d.guestid)as tot2 from t2 inner join
eventguest d on t2.eventid = d.eventid
GROUP BY t2.eventid,t2.numberofplaces;
```

**Error :**

```
 ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
 00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
 Cause:    
 Action: Error at Line: 20 Column: 21
```

Comment: You can't use `tot1` in the select list. It is not included in the group by clause neither it's aggregate.

Comment: I guess posting table structure and expected result will help us and you more.

Comment: Select numberofplaces once inside of the with statement. And add tot1 to group by statement

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement would all help.

Answer (score 0):

You missued  t2.tot1 in group  by  ..
(the  columns not in aggreagtion function in a select must be mentioned  in group by  )

```
with t2 as(
  SELECT numberofplaces, c.eventid, numberofplaces - COUNT(a.memberid) as tot1
  FROM event c
  INNER JOIN eventmember a ON c.eventid = a.eventid
  GROUP BY c.eventid, numberofplaces
)
select t2.numberofplaces, tot1 - count(d.guestid)as tot2 from t2 inner join
eventguest d on t2.eventid = d.eventid
GROUP BY t2.eventid, t2.tot1, t2.numberofplaces;
```

Answer (score 0):

All selected non-aggregated columns should be in the group by list. Therefore, consider using :

```
WITH t2 AS
(
 SELECT numberofplaces,c.eventid, 
        numberofplaces - count(a.memberid) as tot1
   FROM event c
  INNER JOIN eventmember a 
     ON c.eventid = a.eventid
  GROUP BY c.eventid,numberofplaces
)
SELECT t2.eventid, t2.numberofplaces, t2.tot1 - count(d.guestid) as tot2 
  FROM t2 
  INNER JOIN eventguest d 
     ON t2.eventid = d.eventid
  GROUP BY t2.eventid, t2.numberofplaces, t2.tot1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the number of spaces left after removing members and guests.

You should aggregate the tables *before* joining them.  Then use `left join` to get all events:

```
select e.event_id, e.numberofplaces,
       em.num_members, eg.num_guests,
       (e.numberofplaces - coalesce(em.num_members, 0) - coalesce(eg.num_guests)
       ) as num_left
from events e left join
     (select em.eventid, count(*) as num_members
      from eventmember em
      group by em.eventid
     ) em
     using (eventid) left join
     (select eg.eventid, count(*) as num_guests
      from eventguest eg
      group by eg.eventid
     ) eg
     using (eventid) left join
```